# Average of a series, skipping element[0]

Tags: python, numpy, series

I have a column in a dataframe that holds a series of varying size in each row:

```
values
[0.0,2.3,4.6,99,100,200,...]
[0.0,4.6,7.8,10,20,25,10,5.5,12,...]
.
.
.
```

I have computed the mean of each series as follows:

```
from statistics import mean
df['average_values'] = df['values'].map(mean)
df.head()
```

This returns:

```
values                          average_values   
[0.0,2.3,4.6,99,100,200,...]            7.6
[0.0,4.6,7.8,10,20,25,...]              10.5
.
.
.
```

However, each of these series begin with 0.0 and I need to remove this from the calculation in the average column.

**My Attempt**

I tried to create a new column 'nan_values' that would copy the original values column but all the 0.0 values replaced with NaNs:

```
#create new column
df['nan_values'] = df['values'].copy()

#replace the 0.0 in each series with NaN
df['nan_values'] = df['nan_values'].replace(0, np.NaN)
```

I thought I would yield a series that looks like:

```
[NaN, 2.2, 4.4, 5, 3.3, 7.1, ...]
```

I need to calculate the average of many rows of series but skipping element at index 0.

Comment: Couldn't you just multiply the averages with $n / (n-1)$, where $n$ is the length of a row (incl. the 0.0)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove first value by indexing `[1:]`:

```
from statistics import mean
df['average_values'] = df['values'].map(lambda x: mean(x[1:]))
```

Or:

```
df['average_values'] = df['values'].str[1:].map(mean)
#alternative
#df['average_values'] = df['values'].str[1:].map(np.mean)
```

---

```
print (df)
                                     values  average_values
0             [0.0, 2.3, 4.6, 99, 100, 200]         81.1800
1  [0.0, 4.6, 7.8, 10, 20, 25, 10, 5.5, 12]         11.8625
```

If want remove `0` values use list comprehension with filtering or `filter`:

```
df['average_values'] = df['values'].map(lambda x: mean([y for y in x if y != 0]))
```

Or:

```
df['average_values'] = df['values'].map(lambda x: mean(filter(lambda y: y != 0, x)))
```

Comment: This works. I don't understand what the .map(lambda x: mean(x[1:])) does. Thank you.

Comment: It call function to list with no first elemen, check `.map(lambda x:x[1:])`